# VBA If logic using Asc function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that contains a TextBox. I created an `If` function to validate if the user entered letters or not. I am getting a runtime error 13 on my code. Please help me if I can do the if logic correctly.

```
Private Sub cmd_Submit_Click()
    'it will not accept any ASCII variables from 0 to 65
    If Name_Box.Text < Asc(65) Then
        MsgBox "Enter A to Z"
        'Shall not contain any ASCII characters past 90
    ElseIf Name_Box.Text > Asc(90) Then
        MsgBox "Enter A to Z"
    Else

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Apparently you meant `Chr` instead of `Asc`. Then again, you could simply use the literal letters `"A"` and `"Z"`.

Comment: You say letters (plural), but assuming that you corrected `Asc` to `Chr`, you'd still only testing the first letter. What is a valid entry for the field?

Comment: A to Z, small or large letters

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
Private Sub cmd_Submit_Click()
    For i = 1 To Len(Name_Box.Text)
        If Asc(Mid(Name_Box.Text, i, 1)) < 65 Or Asc(Mid(Name_Box.Text, i, 1)) > 90 Then
            MsgBox "Enter A to Z"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting Run Time Error '424'

Comment: Does debugger shows where error occurs? (which line)

Comment: It works, I fixed it, it was the naming convention on the object, I had txtBoxName instead of Name_Box.Text, the run time was naming match error. Can someone please break down the FOR i = 1 loop, so I can understand it, rather than copying.